# The relative phase of photons in two-photon absorption

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-optics, spectroscopy, non-linear-optics

In two-photon absorption (TPA), the relative polarization of the two photons about to be absorbed simultaneously by an atom is crucial in determining the TPA rate. However, there is a lack of discussion in the literature regarding the significance of the relative phase of the two photons in determining this rate. For instance, it's unclear whether the TPA rate of in-phase photons is equivalent to that of completely or partially out-of-phase photons. Additionally, there's the question of whether photons interfere with each other just before TPA since they are simultaneously present in a point in space and time.

I would appreciate hearing your insights on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Second Harmonic Generation (SHG) is also a form of TPA and is most commonly seen in green lasers ... the KTP crystal doing the SHG, after 1064nm pumping it emits at 532nm.

With respect to the interference part of your question ...the energy in the EM field is always conserved ... 2 photons do/can exist in the same space even if they are out of phase.  Yes it would likely be difficult for them to be successful in TPA but they would interact and be scattered so that the next molecule or atom could absorb them for TPA.

In general TPA is a 2 step process, the first photon excites the electron to a level where it can exist for a brief period of time before it finds another pathway down ... while it waits it can be excited to a second higher level.  The requirement for polarization, angle of incidence etc is likely more function of the crystal itself to have absorption. The phases of the photon may not be so important .... the "wait time" varies for each different type of crystal and may be typically long enough .... i.e they do not need 2 photons present within the phase time.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there is no relative phase between two photons. To understand why we can compare a state with two photons to a superposition. So, consider
$$ |\psi_1\rangle = |\psi_a\rangle a + |\psi_b\rangle b $$
and
$$ |\psi_2\rangle = |\psi_a\rangle \otimes |\psi_b\rangle , $$
where $|\psi_a\rangle$ and $|\psi_b\rangle$ are two single photon states and $a$ and $b$ are complex constants so that $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$.

The superposition of two single photon states is still a single photon. Therefore $|\psi_1\rangle$ is still a single photon states. For such a superposition, we can have a relative phase between the two terms as determined by the values of $a$ and $b$.

On the other hand, $|\psi_2\rangle$ represents a two photon state, but it is not a superposition and therefore, we cannot have a relative phase.

Hope that answers the question.

Comment: You raised an intriguing point that hadn't crossed my mind. Thanks! I suppose I should delve deeper into the quantum wave function of the two absorbed photons during TPA. Your answer somewhat implies that one cannot consider an optical phase for a single photon (only quantum phase, that is the phase of the coefficient a or b), right?

Comment: Yes the global phase of a state can always be ignored.